# I am using Willey Latex template. Please help me! \multispan ->\omit \@multispan l.253 ...lticolumn{3}{c}{\thead{24 h rehydration}}

Tags: tables, wiley-article

```
\begin{table}[!h]
    \caption{Two-way analysis of variance describing the influence of nitrogen (N) and water (W) supply on several characteristics of amaranth plants. Significance levels are as in Table 1.}\label{tab:tab2}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{lcccccccc}
        \headrow
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Variables}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{End of stress}} & &  
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{24 h rehydration}}  \\
                       & & N   & Water & N\textit{x}W & & N   & Water & N\textit{x}W \\
        \textit{g$_s$} & & **  & ***   & ***          & & *** & NS    & NS \\
        \textit{E}     & & NS  & ***   & ***          & & *** & **    & * \\    
        \textit{A}     & & *   & ***   & ***          & & *** & *     & NS \\       
        \textit{C$_i$} & & *** & *     & *            & & NS  & **    & NS \\   
        WUE            & & NS  & ***   & **           & & *** & NS    & * \\            
        Proline        & & *** & *     & *            & & *** & NS    & NS \\
        Leaf N         & & *** & NS    & NS           & & *** & NS    & NS \\
        Ammonium       & & *** & NS    & NS           & & *** & NS    & NS \\
        Nitrate        & & *** & **    & **           & & *** & NS    & NS \\
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please include definitions of `\thead`, `\headrow` and environment `threeparttable`. If I comment these command, the code compiles.

Comment: Unrelated `[!h]` is not a good idea, better with `[!htp]`. Why `\textit{g$_s$}` and not just `g_s`? (there are many)

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `wiley-article` replace `\thead` by `\textbf` to get

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{wiley-article}

\usepackage{threeparttable} % added <<<<<<<
\usepackage{caption} % added <<<<<<<<<
\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[!htp]
    \caption{Two-way analysis of variance describing the influence of nitrogen (N) and water (W) 
        supply on several characteristics of amaranth plants. Significance levels are as in Table 1.}
    \label{tab:tab2}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc ccc ccc}
        \headrow
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variables}} &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ \textbf{End of stress}} &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ \textbf{24 h rehydration}} \\
                                                     &  &  N  & Water &      N\textit{x}W      &  & N   & Water &       N\textit{x}W        \\
        \textit{g$_s$}                               &  & **  & ***   &          ***           &  & *** &  NS   &            NS             \\
        \textit{E}                                   &  & NS  & ***   &          ***           &  & *** &  **   &             *             \\
        \textit{A}                                   &  &  *  & ***   &          ***           &  & *** &   *   &            NS             \\
        \textit{C$_i$}                               &  & *** & *     &           *            &  & NS  &  **   &            NS             \\
        WUE                                          &  & NS  & ***   &           **           &  & *** &  NS   &             *             \\
        Proline                                      &  & *** & *     &           *            &  & *** &  NS   &            NS             \\
        Leaf N                                       &  & *** & NS    &           NS           &  & *** &  NS   &            NS             \\
        Ammonium                                     &  & *** & NS    &           NS           &  & *** &  NS   &            NS             \\
        Nitrate                                      &  & *** & **    &           **           &  & *** &  NS   &            NS             \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much indeed!